# Synchronize data between two different databases with different schemas

Tags: sql, entity-framework, etl, data-synchronization

We have an old CRM running on a SQL 2005 database that I have been tasked with linking to the corporate website. At the moment the data in it is managed internally by staff. The problem is that the database is so poorly design in terms of how it stores relational data that using it with something like the entity framework makes it an unenviable task.

So with this in mind I planned to extract the information from the old 2005 database and transforming it into relational tables in SQL 2012 that work with the entity framework and use this to power the website. I’d set this up as a SQL agent job that runs once a day as there is quite a lot of data to be synchronized.

I have also in my business logic for the website written some code to handle inserts, updates and deletes in a transaction so that if the user updates their details on the website, it will update the SQL 2012 data table and, via an API update the 2005 database to have some sort of data concurrency. I have written a test application and this works satisfactorily.

The problem now comes when internal staff update the data in the CRM as using this system it will take up to 24 hours before the data will be updated on the website. So far I have found SQL Data Compare 10 and dbForce Data Compare software which can sync the changes across databases, but this will need to be done manually.

Is there an automated way to update the record in the SQL 2012 table when it is changed in the SQL 2005 database?

Is it possible to use database first for the entity framework and then alter the structure of the models it creates to it makes more sense, but it still work with the legacy database?

Thanks in advance

Comment: SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare do have [command line versions](http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SDC10/Simple+examples+using+the+command+line#), if you are looking to synchronise more frequently.  Might be useful if you go down that route.

Comment: I'm thinking of using views in the sql 2005 database to structure the data in a way that will map over to the entity framework and building the models from the views instead of the tables. I think this will reduce the complexity for select statements at least, and from the website point of view we can use the API's to do the create, update and delete functions.